# Excluding "None" from output of map function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have this code:

```
fileRDD.map(positive)\
       .map(lambda x: [x,1])\
       .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)\
       .take(10)
```

and the output is:

```
[(None, 3194395),
 (0, 240597),
 (1, 224805),
 (2, 210585),
 (3, 198246),
 (4, 202869),
 (5, 92615),
 (6, 60493)]
```

How can I remove the `None` row from my output? (I just need the 0 to 6 results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.filter.html) function on RDD:

```py
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    (None, 3194395), (0, 240597), (1, 224805),
    (2, 210585), (3, 198246), (4, 202869),
    (5, 92615), (6, 60493)
])

rdd1 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] is not None)

print(rdd1.collect())
#[(0, 240597), (1, 224805), (2, 210585), (3, 198246), (4, 202869), (5, 92615), (6, 60493)]
```